# icinga alerts identification

Tags: bash, icinga, icinga2

Is there any way to set identification numbers for each alerts generating the icinga log?

The issue I am facing is, I have different network links configured on icinga. If any fluctuation happened, icinga will send down alerts first. Then it will send recovery alerts. I would like to create a script to find the actual downtime of network..I need to match the downtime with exact recovery time. Since there no identification numbers, i couldn't create the same including down time. What I can do now is to create the script to generate the dates in which downtime happened. Even that will not be actual downtime due to fluctuation.

### icinga logs

[image: image logs]

### script i am using

```
b=$(grep -ir ILL /var/log/icinga2/icinga2.log  |
    grep "Problem" |
    grep "Completed" |
    grep "UV-Jabong_TCL(RECON)_ILL" |
    cut -c2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 |
    uniq
)

echo "UV-Jabong TCL ILL was down on following days"
echo "------------------------------------------------"
echo "$b"
```

I want to include the down time in the script above. Due to fluctuations, I can't find the exact downtime. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question with the mistakes and mis-formatting. Please consider fixing it.

Comment: as of now, icinga will send downtime alerts for even 1 minute fluctuation. I have to find the exact downtime which last more than five minutes or 10 minutes from icinga logs. is there any way to find the same?